# How to access multiple tables through MTM connection in MySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to access multiple tables through a MTM connection on my MySQL database.

Here is an example diagram, which represents my Tables:
[image]

I want to access User, Skill and SkillLevel through only one Sql-Statement. Is there a way of using for example multiple `INNER JOIN`'S?

I have tried using something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM User, Skill, SkillLevel 
INNER JOIN Members ON User.UserMail = Members.UserMail 
INNER JOIN Members ON Skill.SkillID = Members.SkillID
INNER JOIN Members ON SkillLevel.SkillLevelID = Members.SkillLevelID 
WHERE Members.TeamID = 123
```

Can You help me out here?

**EDIT:**

I have set tables after from. With only one, or multiple, I always get

```
"Not unique table/alias: 'projectmembers'"
```

Comment: FROM * doesn't work, specify a table instead.

Comment: I have specified multiple Tables, but now I get the error message as shown in my EDIT

Comment: select col1, col2... from t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.x = t2.y JOIN t3 ON t2.q = t3.w ... WHERE t1.e = 'value'

Comment: Now I get "Not unique table/alias: 'User'"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh) I found the solution! The trick was, to Join via User, Skill and SkillLevel. Also because of the Where Statement, I had to

`Select * FROM Members`

And the solution is :

```
SELECT * FROM Members
JOIN User ON Members.UserMail = User.UserMail 
JOIN Skill ON Members.SkillID = Skill.SkillID
JOIN SkillLevel ON Members.SkillLevelID = SkillLevel.SkillLevelID 
WHERE Members.TeamID = 123 ;
```